# Redirecting route - what is ember way?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my app, I require to user to not use the back button of the browser on the last page. For that I find a way to replacing existing `url` with current page  `url`. so user will stay with same page.

I am using this JS code :

```
init(){//writing at init

        history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
            history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
        });
    },
```

But what is the correct code of ember to replace the above code? what is the correct way to do?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, do you mean that the transition shouldn't be added to history? You can use `replaceWith` instead of `transitionTo` in your app for that.

Comment: How to write for a specific page?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the user from transitioning to another route within your application by aborting any transition made from the [willTransition](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Route/events/willTransition?anchor=willTransition) hook of your last page's route. Add something like

```
actions: {
    willTransition(transition) {
      transition.abort();
    }
}
```

to your last page's route

Comment: It works within the app level transitions. I am looking for a solution to browser level back button

Comment: I think there is an on exit event isn't there. Or window close event. Can you not catch it, cancel it and set the location